# Notify Icon Receives WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK But Not WM_CONTEXTMENU

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010, winapi

I added a notification icon to my dialog based application, and it received WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK when the icon is double clicked on, but it is not receiving WM_CONTEXTMENU when the icon is right clicked or when the icon is highlighted with the keyboard and the context menu key is pressed. I based my usage of the notification icon on the example in the Windows 7.1 SDK Samples. So, I have no idea where I'm going wrong or why this isn't working.

Note: If I change WM_CONTEXTMENU to WM_RBUTTONUP, it receives the event, but the cursor coordinates are wrong.

```
/******************************************************************************/
/* Menu Resource                                                              */
/******************************************************************************/
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
IDR_TRAYMENU MENU
{
    POPUP ""
    {
        MENUITEM "&Show Status Window", IDM__SHOW_STATUS_WINDOW
        MENUITEM "&About", IDM__ABOUT
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "&Exit", IDM__EXIT
    }
}

/******************************************************************************/
/* WinMain()                                                                  */
/******************************************************************************/
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{

    // ... code unrelated to icon

    // Enable Visual Styles
    InitCommonControls();

    // create the main dialog
    if( NULL == (hWnd=CreateDialog(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDLG),NULL,(DLGPROC)WndProc)) )
    {
        MessageBox( NULL, "Error creating the main dialog!", NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR );
        return -1;
    }

    // ... code unrelated to icon

    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0) && IsWindow(hWnd) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0; 

}    
/******************************************************************************/
/* WndProc()                                                                  */
/******************************************************************************/
BOOL CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {

            // ... code unrelated to icon
            hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage( GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_DDCMP), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_DEFAULTSIZE );

            // Setup the system tray icon
            memset( &nid, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA) );
            nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
            nid.hWnd = hWndDlg;
            nid.uID = 0xDDC;
            nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP | NIF_SHOWTIP;
            nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_APP + 0xDDC;
            nid.hIcon = hIcon;
            strcpy( nid.szTip, "DDCMP Driver" );
            Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_ADD, &nid );

            // ... code unrelated to icon

            return true;
        } break;

        case WM_APP + 0xDDC:
        {
            switch( LOWORD(lParam) )
            {
                case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
                {
                    MessageBox( hWndDlg, "This message box never shows up.", NULL, MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL );
                    HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TRAYMENU));
                    if( hMenu )
                    {
                        HMENU hSubMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu,0);
                        if( hSubMenu )
                        {
                            SetForegroundWindow( hWndDlg );
                            POINT pt = { LOWORD(wParam), HIWORD(wParam) };
                            UINT uFlags = TPM_RIGHTBUTTON;
                            if( 0 != GetSystemMetrics(SM_MENUDROPALIGNMENT) )
                                uFlags |= TPM_RIGHTALIGN;
                            else
                                uFlags |= TPM_LEFTALIGN;
                            TrackPopupMenuEx( hSubMenu, uFlags, pt.x, pt.y, hWndDlg, NULL );

                        }
                        DestroyMenu( hMenu );
                    }
                } break;
                case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
                    if( IsWindowVisible(hWndDlg) )
                        ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );
                    else
                        ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOW );
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        } break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            ShowWindow( hWndDlg, SW_HIDE );
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        case WM_QUIT:
        {
            Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_DELETE, &nid );

            // ... code unrelated to icon

            return true;
        } break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is the WndProc from the Windows 7.1 SDK Sample

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND s_hwndFlyout = NULL;
    static BOOL s_fCanShowFlyout = TRUE;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        // add the notification icon
        if (!AddNotificationIcon(hwnd))
        {
            MessageBox(hwnd,
                L"Please read the ReadMe.txt file for troubleshooting",
                L"Error adding icon", MB_OK);
            return -1;
        }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int const wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_LOWINK:
                ShowLowInkBalloon();
                break;

            case IDM_NOINK:
                ShowNoInkBalloon();
                break;

            case IDM_PRINTJOB:
                ShowPrintJobBalloon();
                break;

            case IDM_OPTIONS:
                // placeholder for an options dialog
                MessageBox(hwnd,  L"Display the options dialog here.", L"Options", MB_OK);
                break;

            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                break;

            case IDM_FLYOUT:
                s_hwndFlyout = ShowFlyout(hwnd);
                break;

            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;

    case WMAPP_NOTIFYCALLBACK:
        switch (LOWORD(lParam))
        {
        case NIN_SELECT:
            // for NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4 clients, NIN_SELECT is prerable to listening to mouse clicks and key presses
            // directly.
            if (IsWindowVisible(s_hwndFlyout))
            {
                HideFlyout(hwnd, s_hwndFlyout);
                s_hwndFlyout = NULL;
                s_fCanShowFlyout = FALSE;
            }
            else if (s_fCanShowFlyout)
            {
                s_hwndFlyout = ShowFlyout(hwnd);
            }
            break;

        case NIN_BALLOONTIMEOUT:
            RestoreTooltip();
            break;

        case NIN_BALLOONUSERCLICK:
            RestoreTooltip();
            // placeholder for the user clicking on the balloon.
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"The user clicked on the balloon.", L"User click", MB_OK);
            break;


        // 
        //
        // As you can very plainly see, the Windows SDK Sample ONLY used WM_CONTEXTMNEU
        // 
        //

        case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
            {
                POINT const pt = { LOWORD(wParam), HIWORD(wParam) };
                ShowContextMenu(hwnd, pt);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WMAPP_HIDEFLYOUT:
        HideFlyout(hwnd, s_hwndFlyout);
        s_hwndFlyout = NULL;
        s_fCanShowFlyout = FALSE;
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        if (wParam == HIDEFLYOUT_TIMER_ID)
        {
            // please see the comment in HideFlyout() for an explanation of this code.
            KillTimer(hwnd, HIDEFLYOUT_TIMER_ID);
            s_fCanShowFlyout = TRUE;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteNotificationIcon();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant. Yes, it has a manifest. `... <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/> ...`

Comment: @Hans I did't think the common controls manifest has any impact on the shell and `ShellNotify_Icon`. Does it?

Comment: @David - you're right, looks like NOTIFYICONDATA.uVersion does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notify icon has changed behaviour over the years. For reasons of compatibility with pre-existing code, you must opt-in to the new behaviour. If you don't opt-in then you don't get sent `WM_CONTEXTMENU` messages. Instead you have to respond to `WM_RBUTTONUP`. Even if you invoke the context menu from the keyboard, the system still sends `WM_RBUTTONUP`. You have to obtain the cursor position, in order to know where to show the menu, by calling `GetCursorPos`.

You can opt in to the new behaviour (and `WM_CONTEXTMENU`) as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), by calling `Shell_NotifyIcon` passing `NIM_SETVERSION` after the `NIM_ADD` call. Presumably the SDK sample you are looking at does this somewhere. My guess is that is what is missing from your code.

The key extract from the documentation is in the remarks section:

> As of Windows 2000 (Shell32.dll version 5.0), Shell_NotifyIcon mouse and keyboard events are handled differently than in earlier Shell versions found on Microsoft Windows NT 4.0, Windows 95, and Windows 98. The differences include the following:
>
> - If a user selects a notify icon's shortcut menu with the keyboard, the Shell now sends the associated application a WM_CONTEXTMENU message. Earlier versions send WM_RBUTTONDOWN and WM_RBUTTONUP messages.
> - If a user selects a notify icon with the keyboard and activates it with the SPACEBAR or ENTER key, the version 5.0 Shell sends the associated application an NIN_KEYSELECT notification. Earlier versions send WM_RBUTTONDOWN and WM_RBUTTONUP messages.
> - If a user selects a notify icon with the mouse and activates it with the ENTER key, the Shell now sends the associated application an NIN_SELECT notification. Earlier versions send WM_RBUTTONDOWN and WM_RBUTTONUP messages.

Comment: If he use `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4` just like I said in my post.

Comment: Indeed. The NIM_SETVERSION is what's missing. The Code Project code doesn't have it either. I'd guess it relies on switch statement fall through and it's the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` that does the work there.

Comment: I added `nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4; Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_SETVERSION, &nid );` directly after my call to `NIM_ADD` and that did not solve it. In fact it also broke `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`

Comment: This is getting hard to do in comments, and without your full code. But since your original code did not set the version at all, then it simply would not receive WM_CONTEXTMENU. That is how the system works. Notify icons that operate in that mode handle context menu by listening for `WM_RBUTTONUP`. The system even sends these when you use keyboard to invoke the context menu. Try it and see (when you have removed the `NIM_SETVERSION` code). I agree that my original answer failed to mention `NIM_SETVERSION` and that was poor. I have remedied that now.

Comment: I appreciate your continued help with this, and I undid down vote and applied an upvote for both of you. I got it to work using `GetCursorPos()` and `WM_RBUTTONUP`. However, I'm still confused as to why setting it to version 4 isn't working. I would really like to get it working that way because later I intend to use balloon tips.

Comment: It will work that way, but I have to see it is not terribly clearly documented. It doesn't help that there is a single function for many different operations and that those operations all behave differently depending on the chosen version. Is the SDK sample that you have complete? If so then you should be able to use that as an indication of what's missing from your code.

Comment: Yes, it's complete, and the only major differences I see between my code and it is that it links it's manifest differently and uses GUID's with the NOTIFYICONDATA struct. Both of which I highly doubt would be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should try changing the `uVersion` member of the `NOTIFYICONDATA` structure to `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4`, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that this members value will tell how the `uCallbackMessage` parameters will be interpreted when passed on to your callback function.

You can also have a look at this: [Basic use of Shell_NotifyIcon in Win32](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/StealthDialog.aspx)

I did a bit of research and the following should work for you:

```
memset(&nid, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
nid.hWnd = hWndDlg;
nid.uID = 0xDDC;
nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP | NIF_SHOWTIP;
nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_APP + 0xDDC;
nid.hIcon = hIcon;
nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
strcpy(nid.szTip, "DDCMP Driver");
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, &nid);
```

NIM_SETVERSION (MSDN):

> Shell32.dll version 5.0 and later only. Instructs the notification
> area to behave according to the version number specified in the
> uVersion member of the structure pointed to by lpdata. The version
> number specifies which members are recognized.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the ancient Code Project link you provide is very helpful. It doesn't use `NIM_SETVERSION` and it handles `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` which I bet is what is actually doing the work.

Comment: Still seems to break all messages from the notify icon.

Comment: Okay, so apparently my eyes cannot tell the difference between `NOTIFYICON_VERSION` and `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4`. After I fixed that WM_CONTEXTMENU works as expected. One thing I'm going to hate about Stack Exchange is that you don't seem to be able to accept multiple answers. Both of your answers work! I should be able to accept both of them and give you both your rep points. For now, I'm going to leave the accepted answer to @DavidHeffernan as I now understand that WM_CONTEXTMENU isn't exactly reliable on all platforms. I went through and upvoted all of your comments though!

Comment: It was fun though=) For me, both `NOTIFY_VERSION` & `NOTIFY_VERSION_4` works?

Comment: No idea... The icon gets added when I use `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4` it just doesn't receive any messages. I forgot upvoting comments doesn't give you rep points, so I went to two of your other answers and upvoted them.

Comment: @KristerAndersson: `NOTIFYICON_VERSION` is set to 3, which also enables the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message.